How to verify if some subjects within my group show significant changes
I have a sample I'm testing on 3 occasions, before, during and after a treatment on different cognitive tasks, measuring the reaction times to a stimulus. I used repeated measures ANOVAs, and observed the differences between each T time using Tukey's post-hoc test. It appears that as a whole, the sample does not significantly differ, but some p values are very close to significance.
Now, I want to verify at the individual level, if some individuals appear to have significantly changed or improved. How can I separate my sample between "those who improved" and "those who did not change" ? Or should I do 2 Wilcoxon non-parametric tests analyses on each subject to determine if they improved over time or not ?
I performed my analysis on Jamovi (because it is very beginner-friendly), but a sample syntax from R would be much appreciated also

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I would run a multilevel model. I would definitely keep all three time points, this helps control error. RM-ANOVA, which you did, does account for the paired (tripled) data, but it makes assumptions that are unrealistic, especially compound symmetry. MLMs do not make this assumption
But you should not separate your sample in the way you have suggested. That's sort of like asking if tall people are taller than short people.

A few comments, and suggestions.

Comment; I am not sure what the value is of the "during treatment" data. This is a halfway point of the treatment, and it is not clear what information it provides. You could use the 3 time points to perform some regression, but with only 3 time points... And that seems like a secondary objective. I would just focus on comparing before to after, and see if the treatment had an effect.
Comment: You have paired data; the same subjects were tested at the 3 time points. Using ANOVA looses the pairing, therefore loses power. So I would not use ANOVA.
Suggestion: I would compute the (after-before) differences in reaction times, and then would use a simple t-test on these differences (paired t-test; aka difference-in-differences). That would tell me if the average reaction time changed (2-tailed test) or was reduced (single-tail test; which is what I would use because of its higher power). By using a paired t-test, and a single-tailed comparison (after<before), you should gain some non-negligible power over ANOVA.
Suggestion: Alternatively (additionally?) I would also run a paired SIgn test, to test if the median changed (the mean and or/median may or may not change; obviously if both changed, it is a stronger effect than if only 1 changed).
Suggestion: if the mean and/or median difference between pre and post were significantly different, then I would take a look at the "mid-point", to see how the effect manifests with time (e.g. concave, convex, linear?).
Comment: "Separating" your sample is possible, but of no value. If I cherry pick the subjects who "improved", then the subjects who "did not change much", then those who "worsened", it should be obvious that I will find a "statistically significant" difference between the 1st and the 3rd groups (and if I do not find this at the first attempt, I can be a bit more stringent in defining "improved" or "worsened" and I will find a "statistically significant" result). But this proves absolutely nothing about the efficacy of the treatment, just about the efficacy of my cherry picking.
Suggestion: As an alternative/addition, you can use a quantile test, to compare any quantile of the paired differences to a given criterion (e.g. is the 75th percentile > 0? meaning that at least 75% of the subjects improved. And that may happen even if the mean did not change). Permutation or Bootstrap tests would allow you to test any quantile (including the median), as long as the sample size is sifficiently large.


Thank you jginestet for your VERY in-depth response. The reason I want to separate the "during" part, is because the treatment is a short acting hypnotic, more suited wording than "during" would be "right after", and the after is a few hours later when the hypnotic's blood concentration reaches 0. As the work's data will be used to assess safe driving after the use of the hypnotic, it is important to account for those who were affected, even if the means of my sample are the same. Even if a small handful of people are affected, it is important to take into account for this field of research. A
